# Htaccess redirect to www except a specific file

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I want to redirect non-www to www, and exclude a specific file (eg. testit.php). Cant find a working solution...

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^testit.php
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]
```

This redirects all files, including testit.php (which i want to exclude).

Thanks for help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/testit.php
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]
```